# Don't understand why this was closed

Tags: support

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [RJ9 Pinout for LAN](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71586/rj9-pinout-for-lan)

The reason states that " NE is a site for to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks in a business environment"

I asked a question about my professionally managed network at my work (a large business) and it was closed?

I'd like some clarity as to why? I asked a cabling question regarding a payment device in our network. I also Happen to be the infrastructure manager at my work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about the pinout for a specific host device, and questions about hosts are off-topic on Network Engineering. The question could try to be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), or maybe even on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

A proper network LAN cable is UTP with four pairs of wires, using a specific registered category of cable with 8P8C connectors. What you are asking about is non-standard, and it will be specific to the host.

Comment: Thanks, that's a bit better than a one line answer. 
However I was more asking if anyone had encountered this before in networking or in the enterprise space and if they could provide insight. The host device only states this is a "LAN" port unfortunately

Comment: The community has decided that end-devices (hosts/servers/VMs) are off-topic for NE. We deal with the network (routers, switches, etc.). Proprietary, non-standard things like this are off-topic. The guys on [electronics.se] are more likely to know about something like this, or have access to information about it.